# Ruby Capybara Poltergeist, how to take screenshot for a page with required login

Tags: ruby, capybara, poltergeist

So i am using Cabybara to take screenshots like this

```
Capybara.register_driver(:poltergeist) { |app| Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, js_errors: false) }
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
session = Capybara.current_session
session.visit url
session.save_screenshot('image.png',full: true)
```

But now i encountered a page where i have to login, how can i login and take screen shot of this web page using Capybara ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fill out the login fields, click whatever button submits the login info, then wait until the login completes and then take your screenshot.  Something like

```
session.visit url
session.fill_in 'Email', with: 'user@example.com'
session.fill_in 'Password', with: 'password'
session.click_button 'Sign in'
expect(session).to have_content 'You are now logged in!'
session.save_screenshot('image.png',full: true)
```

although the specific details are going to vary based on the page/fields you're trying to log into